# Access static web-server through managed switch

Tags: networking, web-server, switch, static-ip

I have three devices:

- Windows PC
- Managed switch: D-Link DGS-1510-20
- Linux Webserver with static IP

[Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7CAI.png)

How do I configure the switch to access the static IP webserver from the Windows PC through the switch in a local Network?
(complete networking noob here..)

Answer (score 1):

*Removed first line - Overlooked link Schematic*

A switch is not supposed to access anything but to forward traffic of machines that wants to access a machine within your LAN. In short: a switch is a Layer-2-Relay (See the [OSI-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) or [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) reference model for an explanation of networking layers).

I now assume, that you want to be able to access the webserver on your windows pc which is connected to that switch.

Usually, regardless of whether the switch is managed or not, it should forward traffic to a device without configuration.

To achieve this, your client and your windows-pc must be in the same LAN (say in the same IP-subnet) and either directly or indirectly connected to the switch.

If client and server are not within the same IP-subnet, you may have to configure the switch's routing. Unfortunately, I dont know how to do this on your device.

Also, make sure that the windows firewall is not blocking traffic to your webserver.

-

Note: Switches supporting [VLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN)'s are Layer-3 capable. Otherwise communication between computers across (V)LAN's would be impossible.

To gain a solid knowledge of computer-networking, I recommend Cisco's [CCENT Certification Guide](http://www.ciscopress.com/store/ccent-ccna-icnd1-100-105-official-cert-guide-9781587205804). Even if you don't want to get the certificate it provides great explanations of networking fundemantals for people who have never been in touch with computer networking.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to route the client IP to the server IP-subnet (cant be changed).

Answer (score 0):

*if it's layer 2 switch or asuming  you are using layer2 switch then connect your server and pc to layer 2 switch and configure network adapter ip setting*

**For example**

`Window pc - ip address 192.168.10.3 Subnet mask :255.255.255.0 Gateway : 192 .168.10.1`

`Web server :192.168.10.2 Subnet mask :255.255.255.0 Gateway :192.168.10.1`

`Ensure that both web server and pc is connected to same gateway 192.168.10.1 .. consider this brief example and use your internal ip address you will be able to access server services from pc`